# How do I check if a field in my mySQL database is empty in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to how to check if a field (column) is empty for a specific user.

I have connected successfully to a mySQL database, I have entered a user and I have fields that are empty.  I have a post form that allows users to enter information.  Based on whether other fields are empty, I would like them to fill accordingly.  I would like to use logic to determine whether a field is empty or not.  I am using the following:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if(trim($_POST['listing_link']) == '') {
    }
    else if(empty($listing_link1)) {


        $listing_link1 = $_POST['listing_link'];

        $listing_link1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listing_link']);

        $query = "UPDATE `users`
              SET `listing_link1`='$listing_link1'
              WHERE `email`='$emailstring'";
    }
    else if(!empty($listing_link1) && empty($listing_link2)) {
        $listing_link2 = $_POST['listing_link'];

        $listing_link2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listing_link']);

        $query = "UPDATE `users`
        SET `listing_link2`='$listing_link2'
        WHERE `email`='$emailstring'";
    }
    else if(!empty($listing_link2) && empty($listing_link3)) {
        $listing_link3 = $_POST['listing_link'];

        $listing_link3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listing_link']);

        $query = "UPDATE `users`
        SET `listing_link3`='$listing_link3'
        WHERE `email`='$emailstring'";

    }

    else if(!empty($listing_link3) && empty($listing_link4)) {
        $listing_link4 = $_POST['listing_link'];

        $listing_link4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listing_link']);

        $query = "UPDATE `users`
        SET `listing_link4`='$listing_link4'
        WHERE `email`='$emailstring'";

    }

    else if(!empty($listing_link4) && empty($listing_link5)) {
        $listing_link5 = $_POST['listing_link'];

        $listing_link5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listing_link']);

        $query = "UPDATE `users`
        SET `listing_link5`='$listing_link5'
        WHERE `email`='$emailstring'";

    }

    $result = mysql_query($query);


}
```

?>

This code checks whether there is anything entered by the user when they hit the button for the "listing_link".  If not, then nothing happens.  If something is entered, then it will check to determine if any of the other fields are filled (listing_link1, listing_link2...listing_link5).  The $listing_link1 - 5 variables are supposed to take on the information.

I cannot get the other else ifs to run except for:

```
else if(empty($listing_link1)) {

            $listing_link1 = $_POST['listing_link'];

            $listing_link1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listing_link']);

            $query = "UPDATE `users`
                  SET `listing_link1`='$listing_link1'
                  WHERE `email`='$emailstring'";
```

And continually running the code by hitting the button for the form just replaces the listing_link1 variable with the newly entered information.

Perhaps there is something wrong with the logic written here.  Please help if you can.

Comment: Your code seems incorrect. You have 5 links. What if someone delete send the link3 as empty. Do you update your database link3 value of that user to empty or do you ignore that? Answer to your question is depending on that.

Comment: Cargo cult programming? Copying a post value to a variable, then overwriting that exact same value with the escaped version of the post value?

Comment: yes this is flawed, i realize this, which is why I asked for help.  I want to be able to test whether one field is empty to determine whether to fill another field with the next link...

Comment: is there a way to test if the "field" in the database is empty, as opposed to the variable itself?

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining `$listing_link1` until after you've checked to see if it's empty:

```
else if(empty($listing_link1))
{
        $listing_link1 = $_POST['listing_link'];
```

Flip 'em around:

```
$listing_link1 = $_POST['listing_link'];
if(empty($listing_link1))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this would solve your woes:

```
$empty = 0;
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
  $varname = "listinglink$i";
  if(empty($$varname)){
    $empty = $i;
    break;
  }
}

if($empty > 0){
  $update_field = "listinglink{$empty}";
  $update_data = $_POST['listing_link'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `$update_field`='$update_data' 
               WHERE email='$emailstring'");
}
```

What I do there is spin a loop to check which one is the first empty *listing_link* and as soon as I find it, set some variable to its number and quit the loop. From there it's pretty much simple.

What this does: `$$varname = 1;` is that it takes the value of $varname and tries to use it as a variable name, for example:

```
$test = "groovy.";
$varname = "test";
echo $$varname; // eqivalent to "echo $test"
```

Fun technique :)

Comment: Hey adioe, this solution does not fill any of the other fields except the first (first_link1).  It will only replace the first field when I give the form new input.  None of the other fields change.